# Can't get phone class to float right and stay inline on CSS file

Tags: html, css

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.nav_items {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  border: 5px solid black;
  background-color: darkred;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}

.nav_items li {
  display: inline;
}

header {
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.phone {
  padding: 10px;
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
  position: fixed;
}

h4 {
  padding-top: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
}

h1 {
  padding-top: 0;
  margin: 10px;
}

.nav_items a {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 14px 16px;
}

.nav_button {
  background-color: darkred;
  display: inline-block;
  color: black;
}

li a:hover {
  color: white;
}

.center {
  margin: auto;
  width: 65%;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 100px;
}

img {
  width: 65%;
  align-items: center;
  display: block;
  margin: 100px auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="reel">
  <header id="top-of-page">
    <h4>DRC</h4>
    <h1>NATIONAL SERVICES</h1>
    <h4 class="phone">Call Us Today: <a href="tel:3305589032">330-558-9032</a></h4>
  </header>
  <nav class="nav_bar">
    <ul class="nav_items">
      <li><a class="nav_button" href="main.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a class="nav_button" href="about.html">About DRC National</a></li>
      <li><a class="nav_button" href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
      <li><a class="nav_button" href="vendor.html">Become A Vendor</a></li>
      <li><a class="nav_button" href="customers.html">Customers</a> </li>
      <li><a class="nav_button" href="login.html">Log In</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <img class="construct-image" src="https://media.istockphoto.com/id/1267010934/photo/experienced-engineer-explaining-the-problems-in-construction-works-development-after-recession.jpg?b=1&s=612x612&w=0&k=20&c=SA3ZB024TeuvRX_l_650nAIC3Ebfnf707vkbY1ifYEo="
    alt="image of construction workers on top of building">
</div>
```

Please let me know thoughts

I cannot get the phone class of the h4 element nested within the header element to stay in the header area. Everything I try either makes it disappear or it is scrunched up and appears under the nav bar.

Any ideas?

Also, I am new to coding and am doing this as a portfolio project/learning experience. Any other critiques or advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: have a look at [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_flexible_box_layout/Basic_concepts_of_flexbox)

Comment: Why do you set the position fixed?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the width:50%; and the padding:10px; combined together are not causing it to be pushed to a new line.

If that is not the case, I would try using display:grid; to align the header items horizontally.

Here is a W3Schools lesson about display:grid; which helped me recently:
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp